# Android - Notepad tutorial - lifecycle - some work done twice?

Tags: android, lifecycle

According to the "Application Fundamentals" article, section "component lifecycle", onResume() is always called when a View becomes active, independent of the previous state.

In the Notepad tutorial, Exercise 3, I have found something confusing in NoteEdit.java:
There is a call to populateFields() in onCreate() as well as in onResume().
Wouldn't it be enough (or even better) to have it only in onResume() ?

In such a small example, it will not do any harm if populateFields() is performed twice, but in a bigger App, things can be different ...

Thanks and Regards,
Markus N.

Comment: Yepp, i think calling it in onResume only should be better, too.

Comment: not quite an answer, but if onStop is called and then onRestart , onCreate will not be called...still doesn't explain why it's called in onCreate at all nesides perhaps convention and readability

Comment: onCreate is good for initializing references to stuff, but you want to save the bulk of your state handling for onResume which you correctly note is the appropriate place.
Also note you should do that in an AsyncTask to keep users happy!
The diagram on the Android Activity Lifecycle page is the best reference, and if you want to be strict, program a state-machine activity from that, because there are some subtleties under the right combination of user switching screens, etc.

Answer (score 1):

From a look at Notepad3, I would say you are correct. There doesn't seem to be any reason for them to call `populateFields()` in both `onCreate()` and `onResume()`. `onResume` is sufficient.

Answer (score -1):

I can see where you need it in both places, if application pauses then you would need it in onResume and if your process gets killed or user navigates back to activity then you will need it in onCreate especially if you are doing some pre-processing.

Per the documentation....for onResume() they recommend using it for lightweight calls unlike in onCreate():

*"The foreground lifetime of an activity happens between a call to onResume() until a corresponding call to onPause(). During this time the activity is in front of all other activities and interacting with the user. An activity can frequently go between the resumed and paused states -- for example when the device goes to sleep, when an activity result is delivered, when a new intent is delivered -- so the code in these methods should be fairly lightweight. "*

The Notepad app may want a variable declared if the method was already hit by onCreate not to redo in onResume().

Comment: onResume is always called (even when the process gets killed and the activity is recreated).

Comment: Yeah but users may need to do something in the onCreate before like layouts and such, hence why you might need to call that function there too.

Comment: Right. onCreate is the correct place for instantiating layouts and the like. I was simply saying that if onCreate is called, onResume will always be called after it.